# pronunciation of the sequence '-edness'

Tags: nouns, pronunciation, vocabulary, phonetics

I'd like to know whether the pronunciation of nominalizations from a participle + -ness, such as **fixedness** (putting aside adjectives with full pronunciation such as 'wickedness') is similar to that of adverbs from participle + -ly, as suppos**ed**ly /səˈpəʊz**əd**lɪ/, that is with that syllable being fully enunciated -èd-.

Comment: Are you asking whether the *-ed-* in the middle of *-edness* words is pronounced or not? That is, /fɪksdnəs/ or /fɪksədnəs/?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanx for replying. Yes, that's the question.

Comment: In general, adding *-ness* doesn't change the pronunciation of the root word. Since we don't emphasize *-ed* in *fixed*, it's the same in *fixedness*. But there are probably exceptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the pronunciation of *-ed* in words ending in *-edness* is indeed generally equivalent to the pronunciation of *-ed* in words ending in *-edly,* although *-edness* words are perhaps slightly less likely to take an extra syllable than *-edly* words.

By the way, the pronunciation of words like this is an area of some uncertainty for native speakers. I used to mentally pronounce the word *fixedness* with two syllables until I learned of the other pronunciation, with three syllables, that is still recorded by many [contemporary dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=fixedness&ls=a). Certain *-edness* and *-edly* words also sound awkward no matter how they are pronounced.

I just looked at the description given for the pronunciation of *-edly* by H.W. Fowler in his *Dictionary of Modern English Usage*; it has some useful information (although it is not entirely descriptive, but also partly prescriptive; and not really "modern" anymore since it was first published in 1926). Fowler was basically in favor of sounding the *e* in nearly all words ending in *-edly*, with only a few classes of exceptions: although he acknowledged that this sounded bad for some words, he generally thought this meant these words should not be used at all, rather than thinking they should be used and pronounced as if the *-edly* were *-'dly* or *-'tly.*

Here are the clearest principles and tendencies I know of for the pronunciation of words ending in *-edly* and *-edness*:

- obviously, we must use /ɪd/ (or /əd/, depending on dialect) in any word with *-ted-* or *-ded-* (or any other word where /ɪd/ is used even before the addition of a suffix such as *crooked, naked*; these aren't participles so not directly related to your question).
- An extra syllable seems pretty much impossible when *-ed-* is preceded by one of the following unstressed vowels: *happ**Y*** (/i/ or /ɪ/), *lett**ER**,* (/ɚ/ or /ə/) or *comm**A*** (/ə/). (There are very few words with the *comm**A*** vowel before *-ed,* though; the only ones I can think of are *concertinaed,* *subpoenaed* and *hennaed*, none of which really lends itself to forming a natural-sounding noun in *-edness.*) Examples: *hur.ried.ness, a.ble-bod.ied.ness; be.wil.dered.ness, good-tem.pered.ness.* (Fowler points this out with respect to *-ied* /ɪd/ and *ured, -oured, -ered* /əd/ before *-ly,* and identifies these classes of *-edly* words as acceptable and productive for him.)
- An extra syllable also does not seem to be used after a syllabic consonant: /n̩/, as in *enlightened,* /l̩/, as in *unsettled,* or /m̩/, as in *accustomed.* So we would have *en.ligh.tened.ness, [un.set.tled.ness](http://www.onelook.com/?w=unsettledness&ls=a), [ac.cus.tomed.ness](http://www.onelook.com/?w=accustomedness).* (Fowler doesn't mention this as a general concept, although he does give the example of *-fash.ioned.ly* (as in *old-fashionedly*) which he finds acceptable. He says that words ending in /l̩d/ cannot form "endurable" derivatives in *-ly*, giving as examples **troubledly* and **puzzledly.*) There is an issue, however: with some words, it's a bit difficult to determine if there is a syllabic consonant (which I'm treating as phonemically equivalent to a schwa-resonant sequence) or something else. For example, I treat *determine* as having an unreduced /ɪ/ in the last syllable, so I deal with it in the next section, but [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/determine)'s transcribes it with /ən/, making it an exact rhyme for *sermon.*
- An extra syllable /ɪd/, when not after /t/ or /d/, seems to be possible in rare cases after an unstressed syllable of another type, but usually unacceptable. Fowler finds **experiencedly,* **accomplishedly,* **discouragedly* unacceptable; the same probably applies to **experiencedness,* **accomplishedness,* **discouragedness.* The word *[hallowedness](http://www.onelook.com/?w=hallowedness&ls=a)* seems to have some use. I'd guess the most common pronunciation is with three syllables; I can imagine it being pronounced with four syllables as *hal.low.ed.ness*; but then again the adjective *hallowed* by itself is sometimes pronounced with three syllables as *hal.low.ed.* The word *[determinedness](http://www.onelook.com/?w=determinedness&ls=a)* is also listed by some dictionaries; all the ones indexed by OneLook seem to give the pronunciation with four syllables rather than five, although the five-syllable pronunciation seems somewhat common for the related word *determinedly.* As I discuss above, *determine* might actually have a syllabic /n̩/ in the last syllable for some people, in which case it would fall into the previous category.
- An extra syllable /ɪd/, when not after /t/ or /d/, seems to sound most acceptable after a stressed syllable. There are a number of *-edness* words of this type that seem to be (somewhat) commonly pronounced with /ɪdnɪs/: *[fix.ed.ness](http://www.onelook.com/?w=fixedness&ls=a), [con.fu.sed.ness](http://www.onelook.com/?w=confusedness&ls=a), [bare.fa.ced.ness](http://www.onelook.com/?w=barefacedness), [mar.ked.ness](http://www.onelook.com/?w=markedness&ls=a).* However, not all words with /ɪd/ after a stressed syllable sound acceptable. Fowler lists **boredly* and **skilledly* as examples of *-ly* words that he doesn't find acceptable with either pronunciation; presumably he would have the same judgement of **boredness* and **skilledness* (and I agree that these sound bad). Fowler also doesn't think it sounds good to use /ɪd/ after /aɪ/ (e.g. in derivatives of words like *gratify, satisfy*); his conclusion is that words like *satisfiedly* should not be used. Of course, "should not" doesn't mean "are not". It was hard for me to find a dictionary that gives pronunciation guidance for words of this type, but I did find that Collins gives no extra syllable in *[qual.i.fied.ly](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/qualifiedly)* (in contrast to e.g. *[a.vow.ed.ly](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/avow)*) and this suggests a four-syllable pronunciation for *qual.i.fied.ness.*

Comment: Thank you for your thorough replying. I use LPD by J.C. Wells, but it isually includes literally every possible pronunciation, w/o specifying any sociolinguistic feature.