# How are words ending with "-edly" pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, adverbs

I knew that "-ed-" in *supposedly* and *assuredly* are pronounced out as a syllable unlike when they don't have "-ly". I found a list of words ending in "-edly" ([1](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-end-in-edly)), and found some other similar examples (*amazedly*, *allegedly*, *advisedly*, *involvedly*, *designedly*, *confessedly*, ...). However some words (*bewilderedly*, *biasedly*, *embarrassedly*, ...), look like exceptions(?) since "-ed-"s in these words are not pronounced as a syllable, and such cases seem to be a minority.

Can the pronunciation of words ending with "-edly" explained somehow, such as by some rule?

Comment: Are you sure these are words? Amazedly, involvedly, designedly, biasedly, embarrassedly?

Comment: Note that in words like "allegedly," the original "alleged" has the last syllable stressed; with "bewilderedly," the original "bewildered" does not have stress on the last syllable. I suspect this is relevant.

Comment: Yes, they're adverbs. Even if they're formed from participles with reduced _-ed_ suffixes, like _confessed, amazed, designed_, the _-ed_ suffix gets a syllable in the adverb. The only exception I can see is _bewilderedly_, where the ending is /dərdli/, not /dərədli/.

Comment: Related: [pronunciation of the sequence '-edness'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/365969)

Comment: @YosefBaskin I can't say whether it sounds natural to use those words as I'm not a native speaker of English, but dictionaries had example sentences for some words, "he seemed confused and taken aback, regarding me *amazedly*" (Collins), "let me propose a *designedly* vague criterion" (Oxford). Also I might artificially make phrases like "*involvedly* designed procedure", "*biasedly* conducted research", or "*embarrassedly* ran away", but correct me if they sound wrong.

Comment: It seems all of those words are pronounced with 4 syllables, except the two that started out with 3 syllables (*embarrass* and *bewilder*). For those two, the first option is 4 syllables and the second is 5 syllables. (OED)

Comment: @WeatherVane - But _amazed[ly]_ and _amazing[ly]_ don't mean the same!

Answer (score 3):

> Can the pronunciation of words ending with "-edly" explained somehow, such as by some rule?

No.

Such "rules" fall into four categories:

(i) Those that have as (at least as) many exceptions as compliance.

(ii) Those that are so complex as to be impractical.

(iii) Those that require a thorough knowledge of the etymology of the word.

(iv) Those in which context and tone play an important part in the pronunciation.

Comment: Hysterical yet true.

Comment: While it may fall in your category (ii), I found [these set of rules](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/367255/443664) from a related post suggested by a comment interesting, and it actually explained all my listed cases.

Comment: @xiver77 *I found these set of rules* This is either research that you should have done before asking the question, or context you should have given in the first post.